# jenkins group while in job is not the same as in terminal

Tags: linux, jenkins, permissions

I have installed jenkins on our dev server, and I added the user "jenkins" to some groups for example www-data.

now when I run this command on the terminal:

```
groups jenkins
```

I get this output

```
jenkins www-data
```

and that is ok, but in one of my jobs I created an ssh command that simply does

```
groups jenkins
```

and the result is

```
jenkins
```

as you can see the "www-data" group is missing, so I have some permissions errors.

and even weirder is when I run this command with the project:

```
groups jenkins
```

I get the normal behaviour

```
jenkins www-data
```

so it looks like there is another user with the same name as "jenkins" but he has no groups, and like he is a temp user or something.

Any ideas why this weird bug happens??

Comment: I am getting this same problem. I am running Jenkins 1.594. It's driving me crazy.